# Create checkboxes in php that correspond to MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

I have a php script that pulls information out from my database.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1"); 
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));// Displays the error that mysql will generate if syntax is not correct.
        exit();
    }

//DYNAMIC PHP PULLING IN THE DATA AND SPITTING OUT THE RESULTS
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $picturepath = $row['picturepath'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];

    $dynamiclist = '<table align="center" width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
                        <tr height="150"></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30% valign="top" align="center"><img style="border: #66cc33 5px solid;" src=" ' .$picturepath . '" height="200" width="200" border="1"/></td>
                            <td width="70%" valign="top" align="left"> <br />' . $name . ' <br /><br />$' . $price . '<br /><br /><font>Description:</font><br /> ' . $description . ' <br /><br /><br />
                                <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="keywords" id="keywords" value=" '. $keywords .'"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value=" ' . $name . ' &nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp; $' . $price . ' "/>
                                    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add to Order"/> 
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="center"><td><a href="cart.php">View Your Order</a></td></tr>
                    </table>';
    echo $dynamiclist;

}

mysqli_close($con); //close the db connection

?>
```

And then I have another page where I want checkboxes created for each keyword listed. I'm not sure if I have my db colum set up correctly, but I have a column set up with multiple keywords: `first`, `second`, `fifty`, `none`, and more.

I've tried creating this, but it only displays actual "checkboxes" with no text next to any of them.

```
<?php

require("database.php"); //connect to the database


if(isset($_POST['keywords'])){
    $pid = $_POST['keywords'];
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem "); 
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));// Displays the error that mysql will generate if syntax is not correct.
        exit();
    }

//DYNAMIC PHP PULLING IN THE DATA AND SPITTING OUT THE RESULTS
$option = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $picturepath = $row['picturepath'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];

    $dynamiclist ="<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='". $keywords ."'>";

    echo $dynamiclist;

}
```

The goal is to have a user select an item from the first page, and on the second page, list several checkbox options for that specific item. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, a comma-separated list is a poor database design. Use a separate table with one row for each `item-keyword` pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want text next to the checkbox, you have to put it in the HTML. And if the column contains a comma-separated list, you need to split it up.

```
foreach(explode(',', $keywords) as $keyword) {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='$keyword'>$keyword ";
}
```

Comment: Man, that was so easy! Crazy. Thank you @Barmar now, lastly would you happen to know how to display the keywords that correspond only to the specific item id?

Comment: Put a `WHERE` clause in the query to select the row for that item.

Comment: Got it... WHERE id='$id'"); 
for anyone who might ever find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);

if(!empty($keywords))
{
     foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='$keyword'>$keyword ";
   }
}
?>
```

Thanks!